# Change values in several editText box that influence each other

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying Xamarin with C# and I would like to perform some calculation in `EditText`  box that influences and are influenced by other `EditText`  datas.

And here is my problem, each `EditText`  modify event crash the app.

How can I perform `EditText`  calculation at the time without crash?

This is the `MainActivity.cs` code, I'll comment below where I reach the problem:

```
    using Android.App;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Support.V7.App;
    using Android.Runtime;
    using Android.Widget;
    using System;
    
    namespace FP
    {
        [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
        public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
        {
            RadioButton radioButtonWeight, radioButtonPercent;
            EditText editTextFlour, editTextFlourA, editTextFlourA2, editTextFlourB, editTextFlourB2;
            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
                // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
    
                radioButtonWeight = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioButtonWeight);
                radioButtonPercent = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioButtonPercent);
    
                editTextFlour = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextFlour);
                editTextFlourA = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextFlourA);
                editTextFlourA2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextFlourA2);
                editTextFlourB = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextFlourB);
                editTextFlourB2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextFlourB2);
    
                //FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextFlour).TextChanged += MainActivity_TextChanged;
                editTextFlour.TextChanged += (o, e) =>
                TextFlower();
    
                editTextFlourA.TextChanged += (o, e) =>
                TextFlowerA();
    
                editTextFlourB.TextChanged += (o, e) =>
                TextFlowerB();
            }
    
    
            public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
            {
                Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    
                base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
    
            private void TextFlower()
            {
                if (editTextFlour.Text == "")
                {
                    editTextFlour.Text = "0";
                }
                
                if (editTextFlour.HasFocus == true)
                {
                    Decimal d;
                    //rate = total flour * % rate / 100
                    d = Convert.ToDecimal(editTextFlour.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(editTextFlourA2.Text) / 100;
                    editTextFlourA.Text = d.ToString();
    
                    d = Convert.ToDecimal(editTextFlour.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(editTextFlourB2.Text) / 100;
                    editTextFlourB.Text = d.ToString();
                }
            }
    
            private void TextFlowerA()
            {
                if (editTextFlourA.Text == "")
                {
                    editTextFlourA.Text = "0";
                }
    
                if (editTextFlourA.HasFocus == true)
                {
                    Decimal d;
                    //rate % = 100 * rate / total flour
                    d = Convert.ToDecimal(editTextFlour.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(editTextFlourA.Text);
                    editTextFlourB.Text = d.ToString();
    
                    d = 100 * Convert.ToDecimal(editTextFlourA.Text) / Convert.ToDecimal(editTextFlour.Text);
                    editTextFlourA2.Text = d.ToString();
    
                    d = 100 * Convert.ToDecimal(editTextFlourB.Text) / Convert.ToDecimal(editTextFlour.Text);
                    editTextFlourB2.Text = d.ToString();
                }
                
            }
    
            private void TextFlowerB()
            {
                if (editTextFlourB.Text == "")
                {
                    editTextFlourB.Text = "0";
                }
    
                if (editTextFlourB.HasFocus == true)
                {
                    Decimal d;
                    //rate % = 100 * rate / total flour
                    d = Convert.ToDecimal(editTextFlour.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(editTextFlourB.Text);
                    editTextFlourA.Text = d.ToString();
    
                    d = 100 * Convert.ToDecimal(editTextFlourA.Text) / Convert.ToDecimal(editTextFlour.Text);
                    editTextFlourA2.Text = d.ToString();
    
                    d = 100 * Convert.ToDecimal(editTextFlourB.Text) / Convert.ToDecimal(editTextFlour.Text);
                    editTextFlourB2.Text = d.ToString();
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
```

The `editTextMyObjectName.TextChanged` events run a calc that must change some editText but I see it crashes.

So, I tried to run the calculation if an object has the focus `editTextMyObjectName.HasFocus` but if I didn't do some other error, it seems it doesn't solve my problem.

What is my mistake? And how can I solve it?

Comment: In your case , when you change the text of **editTextFlour** , the Text of  **editTextFlourA** been changed ,so the event `TextFlowerA()` been invoked . Then change **editTextFlourB** . and **editTextFlourA** been changed again . So your code will be in a loop .Which cause the crash .

Comment: you are right @LucasZhang-MSFT I've added the editTextFlour.HasFocus condition and it works property. I've correct the code upper. Thank you!